# LWC lightning-record-edit-form Custom Submit Button with Pre-default Values

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform

sSample HTML Code:

```
<lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Opportunity" onsubmit={firesubmit} > 
 <div class="slds-grid">
 <div class="slds-col slds-size_1-of-2">
<lightning-input-field field-name="field1"></lightning-input-field> 
<lightning-input-field field-name="field2"></lightning-input-field>
<lightning-input-field field-name="field3"></lightning-input-field> 
</div>
</div>
<lightning-button type="submit" variant="brand" label="Save" onclick={saveClick}></lightning-button>
</lightning-record-edit-form>
```

Sample JavaScript Code below

```
firesubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 
    this.fields = event.detail.fields;
}

saveClick (event) {
    const myfield = event.detail.fields;
    myfield.field4 = "Hello";
    this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(myfield);
}
```

On click of Save button, i'm getting undefined error. Can you suggest as how to pre-default value in field before submitting a record through Custom button?

Note:
I followed an approach mentioned in this link [Save & New Button in LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/301809/save-new-button-in-lwc)

Answer (score 2):

I found a good example here ...
https://medium.com/@strusov/lwc-lightning-record-edit-form-set-or-modify-field-values-onsubmit-9f00199bc2a

In this particular case you can do the following:

```
/* form */
...
<div class="slds-form__item slds-hide" role="listitem">
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Color__c">
    </lightning-input-field>
</div>
...
/* end form*/

/* JS. onSubmit */
...
const fields = event.detail.fields;
fields.Color__c = this.selectedColor;
this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
...
/* END JS. onSubmit */
```

Basically include the field in the form and hide it.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

in your code you have

```
 const myfield = events.detail.fields;
```

instead of

```
   const myfield = event.detail.fields;
```

Comment: That was typo mistake. I'm still not able to pre-default values.